# Bash: repeat last N commands

Tags: bash

In bash you can repeat the last command by entering `!!`, or the third last command `!-3` for example.

Is there a quick way to repeat the last 3 commands, without having to type out `!-1; !-2; !-3` explicitly?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

`fc -N -1`

Where the `-N` is the last N commands you want to repeat.

This will open an editor with the last N commands in it. You can edit the commands as desired and when you close the editor, they will all be run in sequence.

Comment: TIL about `fc`.

Comment: As a 10 year Linux user, *never knew of this*. Thanks.

Comment: What about calling them in the same sequence they were run?

Comment: @digiout That should be the normal behavior. You can reverse it if you would like with `-r`.

Comment: on a mac you want to use -0 instead of -1

Comment: Also like to add if you want to make a shortcut for it so you don't have to remember typing `-1` and `-N`, you could write a function `rp() { fc "-$1" -1 }` 

and then simply type `$ rp 4` to open the editor with the 4 last commands. In order to ignore the entries `fc` or `rp` in your history, add the following line to your `.bashrc` file `HISTIGNORE="fc*:rp*:history*"`.

Answer (score 6):

You could also turn this problem upside-down and group those 3 previous commands, for example:

```
echo 1; echo 2; echo 3
```

and then you will be just fine writing `!!`.

Answer (score 4):

Well, not what you expect, but this works:

```
history | fgrep -v history | tail -3 | sed 's_^ *__' | cut -f 2- | bash
```

And you can create a function for this:

```
myFunc(){
    history | egrep -v 'history|myFunc' | tail ${1} | sed 's_^ *__' | cut -f 2- | bash
}
```

So you can call it like:

```
myFunc -3
```

Comment: The result of `history | tail -3 | cut -f 2-` still contains numbers on my machine, because `cut` removes only the one leading space.

Comment: On many systems sh will not generate the same result as bash, even if sh is a symbolic link to bash.

Comment: @RafałRawicki with the addition of `sed` problem solved.
@userunknown `bash` can be used too.

Comment: This is just far too roundabout a way to achieve what is intended, sorry.