# Repeat Last N commands

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script

In bash, I tried writing a script to run the last N commands. For say, N=5

```
for i in {1...5}
do
    !-5
done
```

The problem is that !-5 gets replaced by the 5th-last command on my shell (say time) and the 'time' command runs 5 times.

Can I make any alteration to my script to make it run the last 5 commands on my shell in series?

NOTE: I posted this question AFTER checking out other similar question which did not answer my requirements. The situation were analogous to this:
Qn1 - "How do you print 3 consecutive tildes '~~~' in C++"
Ans: cout<<"~~~";

Qn2 - "How do you print N consecutive tildes '~~~' in C++" 
Ans: Run a loop and do cout <<"~"; inside the loop

The questions marked duplicate are similar to Qn1 from above and what I wanted was the answer to Qn2 from above. So, I debate the fact that it is a duplicate to the previous question.

Comment: Note: I have taken a look at the related question http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/33389/bash-repeat-last-n-commands

Comment: I wanted to execute the 5th last command 5 times. Hence the !-5 inside the loop. Replacing 5 with $i makes things go wrong.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I misunderstood then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `fc -N -1`, an editor is opened with the last N commands.
You can edit the commands.
They are run when you save them.

If you do not want to edit the commands, use the `fc` option `-e` to specify `cat` as the editor:

```
fc -e : -3 -1
```

If you want to use it with an argument for the N, an alias does not help. You can not even have an alias like 'fc -1' and and append the `-N`, because the `-1` needs to be after the `-N`.

So we need to use a function:

```
runlast () {
    fc -e : "-${1:-1}" -1 
}
```

The `N` is set to `1` explicitly if no argument is given; In this case the last command is repeated.

Here is how it works, using `echo 1` to `echo 4` as the last commands:

```
$ echo 1
1
$ echo 2
2
$ echo 3
3
$ echo 4
4
$ runlast 2
echo 3
echo 4
3
4
$
```

(The last line with `$` is the new prompt.)

Comment: I want to bypass the editor and just blindly run the past N commands. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: `-e cat` leads to printing the executed command twice (once by cat, then again by the shell). `-e true` avoids this.

Comment: Hmm... trying that caused an infinite loop... may be related to my `zsh` setup, of course (`zsh` and `bash` should not differ in general here)

Comment: Can anybody help this to add it as an alias command?
Like say : runlast 5 should do the above command with 5 as argument?

Comment: @Yaitzme good idea, see my edit :)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you're trying to do exactly, but you could try something like:

```
eval "$(fc -ln -5)"
```

Or

```
fc -e : -5 -1
```

To re-run your last 5 commands.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this:

```
$ echo yo
yo
$ echo hey there
hey there
$ for i in {2..1}; do eval "$(history -p \!-$i)"; done
yo
hey there
```

From `help history`:

```
-p   perform history expansion on each ARG and display the 
     result without storing it in the history list
```